# Travel with new passport and missing visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, passport-renewals

I am working in Dubai. I came to india to visiting my family. Incidentally, my passport washed in washing the machine along with my dress and the visa page also washed away.

So now, can I travel to Dubai with new passport without a visa sticker on my passport?

Comment: No, you need to get a replacement visa.  The visa stamp/sticker is the ONLY acceptable proof you have a visa.

Comment: How do you plan on convincing the airline that you have a visa in Dubai?  As you were working in Dubai, if you have your Dubai ID, you can approach the UAE embassy, explain your situation and ask them for a visa so you can travel. Note that your Dubai ID is not sufficient for you to travel, as you are not a UAE citizen.

Answer (score 4):

No. You have to present both an active/valid passport, and a valid visa, where appropriate. As Indian citizens require a visa, you'll need to show one.

If you've got one and it's lost or damaged, you will unfortunately need to apply for another one.